# Override variables in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I've started to use `Terraform` lately, and i need some help. I hope it's not too basic. I've the following Terraform data structure.

```
  abc_template = {
    a            = var.a
    b            = var.b
    c            = var.c
    d            = var.d
    ....
    ....
    ....
    k           = var.k                            
  }
```

And then i run:

```
  resource "local_file" "aaa" {
  count      =  1
  content    = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/abc.tmpl", local.abc_template)
  ....
  ....
}
```

I need to create a new template (`xyz_template`), Which should be very similar to `abc_template`, While only a few variables will changed from the original template. What can i do instead of duplicating so many code lines? Is there a way to inherit `abc_template`, and just to override the relevant variables, Instead of creating `xyz_template` which might be very similar to `abc_template`?

Please advise.

Comment: There is no inheritance in terraform as you start working with modules you will realize that copy/pasta is your only tool at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `merge` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html) to produce a new map using a blend of elements from multiple maps.

For example:

```
locals {
  abc_template = {
    a = var.a
    b = var.b
    c = var.c
    d = var.d
  }
  xyz_template = merge(
    local.abc_template,
    {
      d = var.other_d
      x = var.x
      y = var.y
      z = var.z
    },
  )
}
```

In the above example, `local.xyz_template` would have all of the same elements as `local.abc_template` except that `d` is overridden, and it would additionally have elements `x`, `y`, and `z`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a map:

```
variable "global" {
    type  = "map"
    default = {
        name = "TEST"
        addr = "Test123"
    }
}

output "example" {
  value = templatefile("${path.module}/web.tpl", {
    global = var.global
  })
}
```

template:

```
My name is ${global.name}.
```

And you can override values in a map using the merge() function.